# storing english words from dataframe to a list

Tags: python

im working on a dataframe that has many languages.
im interested in English language only hence im trying to save all English words in a list.

this is what I tried:

```
englishSubject=list()
for count,i in enumerate(df['Subject']):
    
    if df['Subject'][count] == (r'\s*[0-9]*[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*\b'):
        englishSubject=df['Subject'].tolist()
```

the issue is that im getting back an empty list. how do i tackle that?

Comment: How you data looks like?

Comment: strings of words, for example: Today is a bad weather. I like blue color etc...

Answer (score 0):

that's not how regex based comparison works on python.

```
if re.search(r'\s*[0-9]*[A-Za-z]+[0-9]*\b', df['Subject'][count]):
    englishSubject=df['Subject'].tolist()
```

Comment: thanks now the list has value. but do you know why is it storing non English ?

Comment: How do you differentiate between English and non English words?

Comment: i wanted this code to get me everything that is written in [A-Za-z] and save it to a list but its doing the opposite